# JsonObjectRequest in Android sending multiple requests

Tags: android, jsonobjectrequest

I am building an android application in which some data is sent to server from the android device, every 1 second for 30 seconds. (total 30 requests to server).

I am using a `for` loop for this :

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++){
//Some data computation
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

I am getting more than 30 enteries at my server end.
Is the JsonObjectRequest is sending multiple requests in every iteration?

Comment: What's your meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Volley makes multiple requests to the server by default (Default Retry Policy).
These Settings can be found in `DefaultRetryPolicy.java`.
So according to this default policy, Volley tries to wait for the response for 2500 milliseconds, however if the response is not received in this time span then it retries for the number set by the DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, i.e., 1.  And the DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT variable  is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.

```
/** The default socket timeout in milliseconds */
public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS = 2500;

/** The default number of retries */
public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 0;

/** The default backoff multiplier */
public static final float DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT = 1f;
```

Now, to stop the multiple request you can configure retry policy for your request object by using the setRetryPolicy() method of the request object.

```
//req = Request
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0,
      DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Reference : [Here](http://www.techstricks.com/avoid-multiple-requests-when-using-volley/)